# How can I change the size of all pgfplots at once (or more general, how to set global settings)?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfkeys

How can I change all pgfplots at once but keep the lable sizes and so on the same?

Another question would be how to set global settings? I set the following e.g. in every plot

```
every x tick label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
every y tick label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
```

Can I set that globally for every plot?

Comment: `\pgfplotsset` is your friend. And for the size there are the options `width` and `height`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

To set options globally for `pfgblots`, `\pgfplotsset` can be used in the preamble. These global options can be overwritten locally in `\begin{axis}[...]`. And they can be changed mid document with another `\pgfplotsset` command.

But caution, some options are not `pgfplots` options but rather `tikz` options. In this case the full path must be given, e.g. `mark` has to be set as `/tikz/mark` in `\pgfplotsset`. Alternatively, these options can be set with `\tikzset`.

The following code shows an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    width=5cm,
    height=4cm,
    every x tick label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
    every y tick label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
    xlabel=X label,
    ylabel=Y label,
    samples=11,
    /tikz/mark=*
}

\begin{document}
With settings from preamble:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=0:8] {(x-4)^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=0:8] {(x-4)^3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Settings from preamble can be overwritten locally:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    every x tick label/.append style = {font=\tiny},
    every y tick label/.append style = {font=\tiny},
]
\addplot[domain=0:8] {(x-4)^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=6cm,
    mark=+
]
\addplot[domain=0:8] {(x-4)^3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

And they can be changed globally mid document:

\pgfplotsset{height=5cm}
\tikzset{mark=x}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=0:8] {(x-4)^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=4cm
]
\addplot[domain=0:8] {(x-4)^3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]